# I want to allow guests to comment on the buddypress activity stream

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have installed Buddypress on my WordPress website. I want people to comment on the activity stream without registration. Right now only logged-in members can comment. Is there any plugin I can use to enhance this feature or do I have to modify the existing code to achieve this?